# Postgres SQL: Hot to get a subcount and totalcount in the same select statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I am looking to get a table with segment, segment sales and segment sales out of total sales.

I have a table that provides me with the segment name and the sales within the segment, how do I add the total sales share information to that table?

My idea was:

```
select segment, segment_sales, segment_sales/sum(segment_sales)
from sales1
group by 1;
```

However, I get the following error: SQL Error [42803]: ERROR: column "segment_sales" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
  Position: 27

Comment: Did you post the correct code? `sales_count` is not present in our query

Comment: thanks I adjusted the error

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions. I think that this does what you want:

```
select 
    segment, 
    sum(segment_sales) total_segment_sales, 
    sum(segment_sales)/sum(sum(segment_sales)) over() segment_sales_ratio
from sales1
group by segment;
```

This query groups together rows that have the same `segment`, and sums `segment_sales` in each group, in column aliased `total_segment_sales`. The third column divides the sum of sales of the current segment with the total sales over the whole table.

On the other hand, if you have just one row per segment in your original table, then it's bit simpler: you don't need aggregation:

```
select 
    segment, 
    segment_sales, 
    segment_sales/sum(segment_sales) over() segment_sales_ratio
from sales1;
```

Comment: Thanks, can you explain what the over() exactly does?

Comment: I tried to convert the latter into % by modifying the 4th line to `(sum(segment_sales)/sum(sum(segment_sales))*100) over() sales_share_in%` but it gives me a syntax error

Comment: @kris030: `over()` makes the aggregate function that preceeds a *window funtion*, so it calculates across a given set of rows (en empty `over()` clause means across the whole table). You can read more [in the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html).

Comment: @kris030: `sum(...) over(...)` is an expression, you cannot put the multiplication in the middle of it. Also you column identifier contains a special character so it needs to be double quoted: `100.0 * segment_sales/sum(segment_sales) over() "sales_share%"`